rms::val.surv function estimated the same survival probability for all cases
I have fit a cox regression model, and used val.surv function to plot calibration plot to compare observed survival probability with predicted survival probability.
model <- cph(Surv(Time, status) ~ variables, data = data, surv = TRUE,
                  x = TRUE, y = TRUE, time.inc = 5)
obs_test <- Surv(test_data$Time, test_data$status)
pred_test <- survest(model, newdata = test_data, times = 5)$surv

val_ests <- val.surv(est.surv = pred_test, S = obs_test, u = 5, 
    fun = function(p)log(-log(p)), pred = sort(runif(100,0,1)))

However, from val_ests, I see that val_ests$actual had the same probability for all samples. So the calibration plot shows a flat line.
May I ask if this is mainly due to small sample size? So that when estimating survival probability from Time and Status it won't be enough to differentiate different survival probabilities?

Are the time and status variables in your global environment identical with the data data frame?  How does obs_test align with test_data?

Dear Prof. Harrell, apologies for the confusion. the obs_test was derived from the test_data: obs_test <- Surv(test_data$Time, test_data$status). I will figure out how to edit the original question as well to make it more clear. Thanks.

And make sure time units are consistent and you have lots of people with time >= 5 units

Please add extra info as an edit to the post and not only in comments. Comments are often seen only by a few people ...
